# Problem with the derivative of Heaviside distribution

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory

How can I calculate the derivative $\partial_{x}\theta(y)$, where the relation between $y\in(-\infty,0)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is not given explicitly, but only by the equation $y=a-|x-f(y)|$, where $f$ is a function from $(-\infty,0)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Notice that the Heaviside function has no derivative in the usual sense. In particular, the derivative (in the distributional sense) cannot be evaluated at certain points.

Comment: Is $y$ differentiable? Are its zeros isolated? What is $y'(x_i)$ at the $x_n$ such that $y=0$? It might help to assume that $a\ne 0$

Comment: $y(x)$ is differentiable, but I don't know its explicit form. So I wonder if it is possible to calculate $\partial_{x}\theta(y)$ without finding the function $y(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively we have $\frac{d}{dx}\theta(y(x)) = \theta'(y(x)) \, y'(x)$ by the chain rule.

By implicit derivation and chain rule we have
$$
y'(x) = -\operatorname{sign}(x-f(y)) \, (1-f'(y)y'(x)),
$$
which when solved for $y'(x)$ gives
$$
y'(x) = \frac{\operatorname{sign}(x-f(y))}{\operatorname{sign}(x-f(y)) f'(y) - 1}.
$$

Thus, since $\theta'=\delta,$ we get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\theta(y(x))
= \delta(y(x)) \, \frac{\operatorname{sign}(x-f(y))}{\operatorname{sign}(x-f(y)) f'(y) - 1}
= \delta(y(x)) \, \frac{\operatorname{sign}(x-f(0))}{\operatorname{sign}(x-f(0)) f'(0) - 1},
$$
where it in the last step has been used that $g(x)\delta(x) = g(0)\delta(x).$

As I wrote at the start of this post, these calculations were done naively. But still I think that they are valid.

---

After looking a bit more into this I realized that since
$$
\delta(y(x)) = \sum_{z \in y^{-1}(\{0\})} \frac{\delta(x-z)}{|y'(z)|}
$$
we have
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\theta(y(x)) 
= \theta(y(x)) \, y'(x) 
= \delta(y(x)) \, y'(x)
\\
= \sum_{z \in y^{-1}(\{0\})} \frac{y'(x)}{|y'(z)|} \delta(x-z)
\\
= \sum_{z \in y^{-1}(\{0\})} \operatorname{sign}(y'(z)) \delta(x-z)
\\
= \sum_{z \in y^{-1}(\{0\})} \operatorname{sign}\left(\frac{\operatorname{sign}(z-f(y(z)))}{\operatorname{sign}(z-f(y(z))) f'(y(z)) - 1}\right) \delta(x-z)
\\
= \sum_{z \in y^{-1}(\{0\})} \operatorname{sign}\left(\frac{\operatorname{sign}(z-f(0))}{\operatorname{sign}(z-f(0)) f'(0) - 1}\right) \delta(x-z)
.
$$

Comment: Hmm, I was just not sure about the chain rule and if it is valid for the Heaviside distribution

Comment: It probably depends on how regular $y$ is.